# Lead.IsConverted shows false in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Lead.IsConverted shows  false in the test class.

```
    Lead leadRec = new Lead();
    leadRec.Account_Groups__c = 'Test;Test1';
    leadRec.RecordTypeId = RecType;
    leadRec.lastName = 'Karthik';
    leadRec.Company = 'Tx';
    leadRec.Country = 'HK';
    insert leadRec;

    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(leadRec.id);

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Try enclosing the LeadConvert within a Test.startTest and Test.stopTest

Comment: Are you referring to leadRec? It will show false until you re-query the lead after conversion.

Comment: I've learned the hard way to include in my asserts the error message such as here: `System.assert(lcr.isSuccess(),!lcr.isSuccess() ? lcr.getErrors()[0].getMessage() : 'null');`. I would agree with @peter that it is a downstream error in some other trigger/validation rule

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer here is: seek more data!

I just tried this code:

```
    public testMethod static void testLeadConvert(){
    Lead l = new Lead();
    l.LastName = 'Threepwood';
    l.FirstName = 'Clarence';
    l.Company = 'something';
    l.Country = 'somewhere';
    insert l;

    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(l.id);

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc); 
    System.debug('is it a success? ' + lcr.isSuccess()); //<--True

    //this line returned my lead with isConverted:true and ids for related contact and account
    Lead leadFromDB = [select 
                       FirstName,
                       LastName,
                       Company,
                       Country,
                       isConverted,
                       ConvertedAccountId,
                       ConvertedContactId
                       from Lead where id = : l.Id];
    System.debug('this lead looks like: ' + leadFromDB);

    // successfully queried contact, would produce query exception if no contact found
    Contact c = [select Id,FirstName,LastName from Contact where Id = : leadFromDB.ConvertedContactId];

    // again success, no query exception
    Account a = [select Id,Name from Account where Id = : leadFromDB.ConvertedAccountId];

    // confirmation in my log of what I got back.
    System.debug(c);
    System.debug(a);

    System.assert(lcr.isSuccess()); //<--assert passed       

}
```

This is about as good a use case for the argument that when you perform an assert against changed data you should always take a trip to the DB (if possible) to ensure that your change arrived safe and sound in the DB.

If I had to guess there is something else that is actually blocking the conversion like a trigger or validation rule on Account, Contact, or Opportunity.

To get more information I would attempt to output the error messages from LeadConvertResult (which also has the Contact, Account, and Opportunity IDs incidentally) right before you make the assertion so that they will be signed-sealed-delivered to your log in a place where you expect them right next to the assert failure.

```
for (Database.Error e : lcr.getErrors){
    System.debug(e);
}
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```

There is one final thing that one of the comments addresses. For best practices, you should add this around your actual statement that performs the conversion:

```
    Test.startTest(); <--new set of governor limits for my logic
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc); 
    Test.stopTest(); <--back to original governor limits
```

This won't have any bearing on the outcome of the tests necessarily, but it is good practice for a number of reasons such as control of governor limits and async code execution.